# Использование JQuery и JSF

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, primefaces

Есть таблица в xhtml файле на JFS. Требуется, при помощи JQuery проверить значения в ячейках конкретного столбца и при совпадении с образцом изменить цвет фона. В js и в JQuery - полный ноль. Никогда фронтэндом не занимался. Знаю только как подключить библиотеку.  Как это можно сделать? Важно, событие должно происходить при загрузке страницы.

Comment: У JSF в целом и в PrimeFaces в частности есть свой собственный весьма развитый фронтенд-код. Если вам понадобилось использовать jQuery вместе с JSF, значит вы плохо знаете JSF.

Comment: Наверное, если я упомянул обязательное использование JQuery, то это не просто так. А высказывать свое мнение об уровне знаний, даже не пытаясь вникнуть в текст вопроса...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте такой пример, таблица с одним столбцом, при загрузке страницы отработает JQuery и изменит фон ячейки.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:dataTable value="#{order.orderList}" var="o">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Order No</f:facet>
            <h:outputText styleClass="order" value="#{o}" />
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.order').each(function (index) {
                // какое-то условие
                if ($(this).text().trim() > 5) {
                    $(this).parent().css({'background-color': 'red'});
                }
            });
        });
    //]]>
    </script>
</h:body>
```

Comment: К сожалению, не получается. Просто выражение, которое меняет фон у ячеек с кпассом .rr типа $(".rr").css("background-color", "blue"); срабатывает, но метод .each никак не могу заставить заработать. Мне надо перебрать ячейки с классом "rr" (текстовае значение) сравнить с эталоном строки, и если совпадают, изменить фон.  Пишу так  $(".rr").each(function() {  }

Comment: Добавил новый рабочий пример. Вот так получим содержимое ячейки $(this).text() , а вот так получим родителя т.е. тег <td> ---> $(this).parent(), дальше меняем фон $(this).parent().css({'background-color': 'red'});

Comment: Спасибо.  Перебор заработал, но не срабатывает сравнение.  Пишу   if (this.text().trim() == "red") {
         $(this).css("color", "blue");
     }   Без if все отрабатывает.  И еще непонятно, зачем передавать аргумент index в функцию?

Comment: Все, разобрался.  Пропустил $ в операторе сравнения.  Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: Надо не this.text(), а $(this).text(), т.о. $(this) вернет ссылку на объект перечисления. Аргумент index это порядковый номер для перечисляемых элементов, можно и не передавать, оставить скобки пустыми.